# Requesting assistance regarding basic php PDO connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

(Disclaimer: 
This code is from Chapter 11 of the book "PHP Solutions: Dynamic Web Design Made Easy"  Copyright David Powers, 2006.  It is a great resource in my opinion, speaking from the perspective of an obviously very novice web developer.  [Here](http://www.apress.com/open-source/php/9781430232490) is the source code for the entire book.  Some of this code is a bit different from what is in the book itself.  )

** edit: corrected code according to first comment by Benny Hill.

** edit for Solution: case closed, with the help of Benny Hill.
Solution: After correcting my code, I had to manually direct the browser to the file: http:// localhost/siteG/mysql/pdo.php (<-- this is correct), versus dragging the file straight into the browser, producing this URL: file:///C:/wamp/www/siteG/mysql/pdo.php This is what was messing me up.  Thank you Benny Hill.

---

Hello,

I am having trouble connecting to my DB with the following code.

Here is what my browser outputs:

```
query($sql); $error = $conn->errorInfo(); if (isset($error[2])) die($error[2]); //    find out how many records were retrieved $numRows = $result->fetchColumn(); echo $numRows; ?>
```

Here is the code :

Connection File: conn_pdo.inc.php

```
<?php
// call this function like this: $conn=dbConnect('admin')  or, admin can be query
function dbConnect($type) {
if ($type == 'query') {
    $user = 'root';
    $pwd = 'root';
  }
  elseif ($type == 'admin') {
    $user = 'root';
    $pwd = 'root';
  } else {
    exit('Unrecognized connection type');
    }
}

function dbConnect() {
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basicgallery', $user, $pwd);
    return $conn;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Cannot connect to database';
    exit;
    }
} ?>
```

the "query" file:   pdo.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
  include('../includes/conn_pdo.inc.php');
  // connect to MySQL
  $conn = dbConnect('query');
  // Prepare sql query
  $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images';
  // submit the query and capture the result
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $error = $conn->errorInfo();
  if (isset($error[2])) die($error[2]);

  // find out how many records were retrieved
  $numRows = $result->fetchColumn();

  echo $numRows;
  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the browser is outputting raw php code?

Comment: Lots of problems here. You have two `dbConnect` functions. "fucntion" is spelled wrong. There should not be a semi-colon here: `function dbConnect();`...

Comment: Dang, sorry for those dumb mistakes.  I corrected them, however I am still receiving the same message from the browser upon loading the pdo.php file.  Any other errors you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conn_pdo.inc.php file should look like this:

```
<?php
// call this function like this: $conn=dbConnect('admin')  or, admin can be query
function dbConnect($type){
    if ($type == 'query'){
        $user = 'root';
        $pwd = 'root';
    }
    elseif ($type == 'admin'){
        $user = 'root';
        $pwd = 'root';
    }else{
        exit('Unrecognized connection type');
    }    
    try{
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basicgallery', $user, $pwd);
        return $conn;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo 'Cannot connect to database';
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

I removed the second declaration of `dbConnect` and the closing brace for the first declaration of `dbConnect`.

Comment: Benny, your assistance is greatly appreciated.  Does this code work for you?  It still does not work for me-- the browser is still outputting the same message.

Comment: @PatrickMeaney This works for me. I get the message "Cannot connect to database".

Comment: @PatrickMeaney - I just now changed the username/password and table name to values that are valid in my environment - the query works and echoed out the number of rows I have in the table I used.

Comment: Excellent, I am glad to hear that it is working.  I will test it later today on a different machine & server.

Comment: @PatrickMeaney - you may want to copy/paste the code on this page - I have a feeling you've got a stray `?>` somewhere in your source code. If you're seeing PHP code in your browser it's because the server has stopped parsing PHP code.

Comment: I copied and pasted directly.  Still the same problem.  But, again, thank you for your time and experience Benny!

Comment: you're the man.  I found the problem.  I figured just dragging the file into the browser would load the file from localhost, but doesn't (though I could swear it does on my other computer).

instead, I had to manually direct the browser to the file:
http:// localhost/siteG/mysql/pdo.php
is correct, versus: file:///C:/wamp/www/siteG/mysql/pdo.php  is what was messing me up.  Thanks again, someday I will "pass it on".

Comment: @PatrickMeaney - excellent, glad you've got it working. Good luck with learning PHP!

Comment: Here is the output of the above code, using a simple example in the database of the filenames of images for a basic image gallery (formatted into 3 columns):

image_id filename caption
1 img1.jpg This is img1
2 img2.jpg This is img2
3 img3.jpg This is img3
4 img4.jpg This is img4
5 img5.jpg This is img5
6 img6.jpg This is img6
7 img7.jpg This is img7
8 img8.jpg This is img8